# Excel VBA - Use Application.Caller to get cell coords for an image

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a script that has a "delete tool" button. A tool will take up 5 rows. So, my code will delete the 5 rows when the X button is hit, and also will delete the X button because it is no longer necessary.

The only issue I am having is how do I find the cell address of the picture that was clicked? Below is the code I have begun to use.

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    Dim Check As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim m As Picture
    Dim strCallerTyp As String

    strCallerTyp = TypeName(Application.Caller)

    Select Case strCallerTyp
        Case "String"
            Check = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to remove this tool?", vbYesNoCancel, "Delete Tool")
            If (Check = 6) Then
                MsgBox Sheets("sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell '*THIS LINE*'
            End If
        Case "Error"
            MsgBox "Error"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Why is this line (marked in code):

`MsgBox Sheets("sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell`

opening a message box that says "Excel" instead of a coordinate?

TIA!

Comment: I'm voting this up simply because I was 100% unaware of the `Shape.TopLeftCell` property. Super userful!

Comment: @DanWagner It is a very useful tool in VBA! It returns the cell in which the top-left corner of your object is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add .Address to the end of the line

MsgBox Sheets("sheet1").Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address

Hth,
Ojf

Comment: Weird.. Earlier I tried that and the ouput wasn't right either... I must have typed something wrong. It's working now though, thanks! I'll accept once I can.